# PHP of Phpmyadmin does not execute but other php scripts work

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, apache2, execution

When calling the phpmyadmin website a "save file" dialog appears for `application/x-httpd-php-` so my server does not execute the phpmyadmin php script but transfers the code to my browser. Other php such as roundcube or ispconfig work as supposed.

- I found a topic here that stated to enable short_open_tags in the php.ini but that did not help (i.e. it already was enabled by default).
- Also, I checked to have installed and enabled the apache 2 php5 modules.
- In the logs files obviously no errors are listed.
- I wondered if the phpmyadmin.conf is even regarded, as only a symlink is pointing to /usr/share/phpmyadmin in the etc/apache2/conf.d/ directory, but since the Alias /phpmyadmin works, this is not the problem.
- I checked the apache2 config files but could not find anything wrong.

Nevertheless I'd like to post some here:
apache2.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
DefaultType None
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
Include conf.d/
Include sites-enabled/
```

phpmyadmin.conf

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
                php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
                php_flag track_vars On
                php_flag register_globals Off
                php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
                php_value include_path .
                php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
                php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
    AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

These are the enabled apache 2 mods:

```
 actions alias auth_basic auth_digest authn_file authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_user autoindex cgi dav dav_fs deflate dir env fcgid include mime negotiation php5 reqtimeout rewrite ruby setenvif ssl status suexec suphp
```

and the installed packages related to apache 2 or php:

```
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                  5.4.4-14                     i386         server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  libapache2-mod-suphp                 0.7.1-3                      i386         Apache2 module to run PHP scripts with the owner permissions
ii  php-auth                             1.6.2-1                      all          PHP PEAR modules for creating an authentication system
ii  php-pear                             5.4.4-14                     all          PEAR - PHP Extension and Application Repository
ii  php5                                 5.4.4-14                     all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php5-cgi                             5.4.4-14                     i386         server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
ii  php5-cli                             5.4.4-14                     i386         command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                          5.4.4-14                     i386         Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  php5-curl                            5.4.4-14                     i386         CURL module for php5
ii  php5-gd                              5.4.4-14                     i386         GD module for php5
ii  php5-imagick                         3.1.0~rc1-1+b2               i386         ImageMagick module for php5
ii  php5-imap                            5.4.4-14                     i386         IMAP module for php5
ii  php5-intl                            5.4.4-14                     i386         internationalisation module for php5
ii  php5-mcrypt                          5.4.4-14                     i386         MCrypt module for php5
ii  php5-mysql                           5.4.4-14                     i386         MySQL module for php5
ii  phpmyadmin                           4:3.4.11.1-2                 all          MySQL web administration tool
ii  suphp-common                         0.7.1-3                      i386         Common files for mod suphp
ii  apache2                              2.2.22-13                    i386         Apache HTTP Server metapackage
ii  apache2-doc                          2.2.22-13                    all          Apache HTTP Server documentation
ii  apache2-mpm-prefork                  2.2.22-13                    i386         Apache HTTP Server - traditional non-threaded model
ii  apache2-suexec                       2.2.22-13                    i386         Standard suexec program for Apache 2 mod_suexec
ii  apache2-utils                        2.2.22-13                    i386         utility programs for webservers
ii  apache2.2-bin                        2.2.22-13                    i386         Apache HTTP Server common binary files
ii  apache2.2-common                     2.2.22-13                    i386         Apache HTTP Server common files
ii  libapache2-mod-fcgid                 1:2.3.6-1.2                  i386         an alternative module compat with mod_fastcgi
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                  5.4.4-14                     i386         server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  libapache2-mod-ruby                  1.2.6-2                      i386         Embedding Ruby in the Apache2 web server
ii  libapache2-mod-suphp                 0.7.1-3                      i386         Apache2 module to run PHP scripts with the owner permissions
```

I am running out of ideas here.
I need to mention, that I mistakenly upgraded directly from Debian 5 to Debian 7 which was a big pain and caused a lot of trouble. This current problem is part of it and there might be weird causes involved, such as depreciated config entries or whatever.

Comment: what version of phpmyadmin do you have installed?

Comment: 4:3.4.11.1-2, I added the installed packages in the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what is the version of PHP?

If other .php scripts work except for phpMyAdmin, the is pretty safe to assume something is wrong with phpMyAdmin installation. (either with the files or the Virtual Host)

---

**Troubleshoot:**

1. Can you run another script in phpMyAdmin directory? Try with a file containing phpinfo(); If it does not work then the problem is in your apache configuration.
2. If the above is true, then the parser is not recognising phpMyAdmin/index.php as a php file, for some reason. Try reinstalling phpMyAdmin.

---

**Thoughts:**

Remove `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`. You should not need it.

In PHP 5.4 *`magic_quotes_gpc`* was removed. If you're running PHP5, remove that line.

As of PHP 4.0.3, *`track_vars`* is always turned on, so remove it also.

As of PHP 4.2.0, *`register_globals`* this directive defaults to off. In PHP5.3 *`register_globals`* is deprecated, as of PHP5.4 *`register_globals`* was removed. SO if running PHP > 4.2.0 remove that line.

Comment: Phpinfo() works in the phpmyadmin directory (usr/share/phpmyadmin).

Comment: Now I feel stupid... I purged phpmyadmin did and apt-get autoclean and reinstalled it. It works! Honestly, I did that in the beginning of this odisee but it did not help.

Comment: Glad it's working now. Anyway, see my edited answer, the bottom part.

Comment: The part about deprecation is important even in dev environments. I had my share of troubles with default implementations of virtual hosts

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following, which tells the server to parse PHP files within the phpMyAdmin directory

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin>
  Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
  allow from all
  AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  Require all granted
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
  FCGIWrapper /path/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
  FCGIWrapper /path/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

During phpmyadmin configure, you might have used Unix Socket connection method for MySQL database, you should actually use TCP/IP. And after that select localhost and default port[leave blank] during configuration and you are done. Change it again by typing in terminal:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install php-mysql and libapache2-mod-php in order to your php install be able to communicate with apache and mysql. PhpMyadmin wont communicate with your PHP installation without those packacges.

So try running the following commands and restart apache2 after.

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that server wasn't parsing PHP in the phpMyAdmin directory.
I have added :

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin>
  allow from all
  Require all granted
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</Directory>
```

into my phpMyAdmin.conf (in etc/httpd/conf.d/) and that did the job.

Server is on CentOS 7.6.1810