# php files in phpmyadmin directory not executed

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am using Centos 7 / PHP 5.4.16 / phpmyadmin 4.4.15.5

httpd.conf contains:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

php files in var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/ will be executed correctly. But php files situated in /etc/share/phpmyadmin/ will not.

http://XX.XX.XX.XX/phpmyadmin/ produces a file download in any browser so I have no access to phpmyadmin.

My question is similar to:
[PHP of Phpmyadmin does not execute but other php scripts work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423745/php-of-phpmyadmin-does-not-execute-but-other-php-scripts-work)

But the difference is ANY php script in /etc/share/phpmyadmin/ will fail (not executed) including a phpinfo.php file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It took me 24 hours. If you have the same problem and you installed Plesk, this is the way:

Comment: Enter plesk control panel, go to domains, select a domain, go to databases, on the left go to database servers, the small icon on the very left saying "webadmin" will lead you to https://XX.XX.XX.XX:8443/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/index.php and this is the way to access phpmyadmin :-(